# Beginner's iOS issue (from tutorials)

Tags: ios, ios7

This may seem stupid but this is the first time I am trying to write some iOS code and am using some tutorial which tells me to add some code and explains what it did few lines later. I was able to create a basic square on the screen and now the next few lines were to make sure that the square drops to the bottom of the simulator. I added and compared the code but the square doesn't drop like the code it should. Here is what I wrote.

```
UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
square.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


//UICollisionBehavior* _collision;

[self.view addSubview:square];

UIDynamicAnimator* _animator;
UIGravityBehavior* _gravity;

_animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

_gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[square]];
[_animator addBehavior:_gravity];
```

Can someone tell me what is it that I am doing wrong? Or is the code incorrect someway? Is there any other simpler way to begin iOS development

Thanks

Comment: If you've never done any iOS development, you sure shouldn't be starting with a tutorial about UIDynamicAnimator!

Comment: I've never even heard of `UIDynamicAnimator`.

Comment: @nhgrif `UIDynamicAnimator` was introduced in iOS 7 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I know how to Google.  I was mostly just emphasizing matt's point.

Comment: Yes, this probably isn't the best way to get introduced to iOS programming. They are many introductory iOS tutorials.

Comment: I wasn't sure where and how to begin then. I just googled on what would be a good tutorial for someone like me and iOS by Tutorials. Where do I begin if not this book?

Comment: There are lots of good tutorials here - http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials and you the Stanford courses available on iTunes U are also highly recommended - https://itunes.stanford.edu

Comment: @Paulw11 Thats actually where I got the pdf from. This is the book link that I am looking at when I started.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-7-by-tutorials

Comment: Does that book introduce `UIDynamicAnimator` early on? As others here have said, I haven't heard of that either until now.  It seems like quite an advanced topic.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes its actually in second chapter itself.

Comment: Ok.  Well, I haven't read that book so it may be unfair of me to criticise it, but introducing a class like that, that you will probably never use again in chapter 2 seems strange.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there some book/ pdf that you suggest I should begin with? I am all ears so that I can learn iOS more easily.

Comment: @SubratoM If you look at my bio you will know what I would recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works:

```
@interface DPViewController ()
{
   UIDynamicAnimator* _animator;
   UIGravityBehavior* _gravity;
   UICollisionBehavior* _collision;
}
```

Your mistake is declare _animator, _gravity in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thank you. The pdf I am referring to didnt specify that I should be adding these variables in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/Reference/Reference.html     hope can help you,and I also see this class for the first time

Comment: theAnimator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self];
    UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ballView]];
    [theAnimator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];

Comment: UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ballView]];
    [collisionBehavior setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary:YES];
    [theAnimator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];

    UIDynamicItemBehavior *itemBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[ballView]];
    [itemBehavior setElasticity:0.6];
    [theAnimator addBehavior:itemBehavior];
    [collisionBehavior setCollisionDelegate:self];